# Where on hasmany in sequelize with count

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sequelize.js

I am not the best at UML/database diagrams but the following hopefully shows my DB design (MsSQL)

[image]

I have a "Location" table with zero to many pallets assiociated with it (there are 0-many pallets IN a location). However that location can be one of two types, location x or y. This diagram simplifies it, but there are many different types of location, and very different fields for each type.

I am using Sequelize as an ORM, and trying to figure out how to do a particular query. I think I am close but quite stuck.

What I need is:

Select a single LocationTypeX where "active" is true, and where its corresponding Location has less than 10 pallets in it.

Previously I have gone and got all LocationTypeX where "active" is true. Included Location and Pallet (on location) and did it all in code to figure out which location is relavent. however that is taking forever, as there are thousands of Locations and loads of pallets spread out through them.

All I am after is to show the Location Name. That is it. But the Location name of one that matches the above condition. Hopefully someone can help?

So far I have

```
models.Location.findAll({
  group: ['Location.id', 'Pallets.id'],
  attributes: ['Location.id', 'Pallets.id', [models.sequelize.fn('COUNT',models.sequelize.col('Pallets.id')), 'PalletCount']],
  include: [{
    model: models.Pallet,
    attributes: []
  }]
}).then((ret)=> {
  console.log(ret);
});
```

But this doesn't do the "active" check. And also doesn't do the where clause on the amount of pallets. Back to square one

Comment: Run Sql profiler and check actual query

Comment: @MikhailLobanov why? The query I have at the moment is still far off

Comment: Sorry, my English is not excellent. What means 'far off'? There are no sql query when you run your command `models.Location.findAll({`?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to answer my own question with raw SQL that I can use in Sequelize. However I would still be interested to know how to do it in Sequelize

```
models.sequelize.query(
  `SELECT TOP 1 Locations.id, Locations.name FROM LocationTypeX
  INNER JOIN Locations ON LocationTypeX.LocationId = Locations.id
  LEFT JOIN Pallets on (Locations.id = Pallets.LocationId)
  WHERE LocationTypeX.active = 1
  GROUP BY Locations.id, Locations.name
  HAVING COUNT(Pallets.id) < 3`
, { type: models.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
```